# Data from page 2 of reqres.in/api/users displays on 'All' page and filter list, but appears blank when clicked from filter

Tags: javascript, fetch

This JavaScript code fetches user data from the 'https://reqres.in/api/users' API. It populates a dropdown list (nameFilter) with unique user names fetched from multiple API pages. The user data is displayed in a user-list element, where each user is represented by a user-box containing their name, avatar, ID, and email. Pagination buttons are created to navigate through the fetched user data.

When a user selects a name from the dropdown, it filters the displayed users. If 'All' is selected or no name is chosen, all users are shown with pagination. However, there are issues when selecting a specific user from the dropdown: the user data appears on the 'All' page, but clicking the same user in the filter list results in a blank display.

The code also includes event listeners for the name filter change, creating pagination buttons, and an initialization function (init()) that sets up the initial state by populating the filter and rendering users.

```
const userList = document.querySelector('.user-list');
    const nameFilter = document.getElementById('nameFilter');
    const paginationContainer = document.getElementById('pagination');

const apiUrl = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';
let currentPage = 1;
let totalPages = 1;
let allUsers = [];

async function fetchUsers(page) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}?page=${page}`);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('Fetched data for page ' + page + ':', data);
    totalPages = data.total_pages;
    return data.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    return [];
  }
}

async function fetchUserNames() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}?page=1`);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    const totalPages = data.total_pages;

    const names = new Set(['All']);
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
      const pageResponse = await fetch(`${apiUrl}?page=${i}`);
      const pageData = await pageResponse.json();
      const pageNames = new Set(pageData.data.map(user => user.first_name));
      pageNames.forEach(name => names.add(name));
    }

    return Array.from(names);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching user names:', error);
    return [];
  }
}

async function populateNameFilter() {
  const names = await fetchUserNames();
  names.forEach(name => {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = name;
    option.textContent = name;
    nameFilter.appendChild(option);
  });
}

async function renderUsers() {
  try {
    allUsers = await fetchUsers(currentPage);
    const selectedName = nameFilter.value;
    const filteredUsers = (selectedName === 'All' || !selectedName)
      ? allUsers
      : allUsers.filter(user => user.first_name === selectedName);

    userList.innerHTML = '';

    filteredUsers.forEach((user, index) => {
      const userBox = document.createElement('div');
      userBox.className = 'user-box';
      const nameBar = document.createElement('div');
      nameBar.className = 'name-bar';
      nameBar.textContent = `${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}`;
      const userImage = document.createElement('img');
      userImage.src = user.avatar;
      userImage.alt = `${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}`;
      const userDetails = document.createElement('div');
      userDetails.className = 'user-details';
      userDetails.innerHTML = `
        <p>ID: ${user.id}</p>
        <p>Email: ${user.email}</p>
      `;
      userBox.appendChild(nameBar);
      userBox.appendChild(userImage);
      userBox.appendChild(userDetails);

      if (index % 2 === 0) {
        userBox.classList.add('even-box');
      } else {
        userBox.classList.add('odd-box');
      }

      userList.appendChild(userBox);
    });

    if (selectedName === 'All' || !selectedName) {
      createPaginationButtons();
    } else {
      paginationContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear pagination buttons if a specific user is selected
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error rendering users:', error);
  }
}

nameFilter.addEventListener('change', () => {
  currentPage = 1;
  renderUsers();
});

function createPaginationButtons() {
  paginationContainer.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.textContent = i;
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      currentPage = i;
      renderUsers();
    });
    if (i === currentPage) {
      button.classList.add('active');
    }
    paginationContainer.appendChild(button);
  }
}

async function init() {
  await populateNameFilter();
  await renderUsers();
}

init();
```